# How to determine the content step value of scrollarea

Tags: c++, user-interface, scrollbar

I'm making my own UI from scratch using OpenGL that is why I'm asking this and please don't make any discouragement as this is just a hobby project.

Currently, I'm stuck implementing how this scrollbars **really work**. In my current implementation, the `content` scrolls at the **wrong step value** as well as the `thumb`, meaning, I set the value manually like 1px step for each of them.

The structure of my scrollbar implementation is describe as follows:

- I draw scrollbars i.e the main rectangle where the 3 button lies.
- Those 3 buttons are, `thumb`, `buttonBack` and `buttonNext`.
- All of them do the basic logic of scrollbars i.e when I click each one of them, they **moved**. But the whole part(scrollbar) don't know how to scroll `contents`
- So what I did is: I make another object and I call it `scrollarea`
- It has two scrollbars, vertical and horizontal scrollbar.
- I made a function called `scrollToX` and `scrollToY` which
  does what I named to them.
- But the step values I set to them are
  manually set up.

I try to google some `scrollbar`, `scrollarea`, `scrollview` or whatever you call to that scrollable rectangle thing, but all I see are implementation and I cannot find any guides how to build your own. I have no choice but to look at their implementation. I try my best to comprehend what they did but their implementation of how their whole UI structure is very different to mine, and I cannot find anything useful there.

So I ask again here if anybody can explain me well **how to make a properly functional scrollbar**.

Most specific things I'm really concerned of are:

- How do I determine the `thumb step value`?
- How do I determine the `content step value`?

Answer (score 0):

All of these depend on your content -

- Is it just an image ? If so, you only need to change the offset depending on the size of the image.
- Is it a list of values like in Windows explorer ? Then you need to create a data structure first that contains all of it, and shows the content that fits within the window as it scrolls.

OpenGL does not fit into this discussion.

Comment: Let say its kinda like an image, how to obtain those values? What would be the formula?